# Determining if particular point is near country or state boundary

Tags: c#, api, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

I'm developing an accessibility Add-On for flight simulators that allows a blind person to fly. The App is coded in c#.

I can easily get the GPS location of the user's Aircraft. What I want to be able to do is tell the user if they are within range of a country or state/province boundary.

All the output is done using text-to-speech, so I'm not actually drawing a map, I just need the data and to understand how to process it. Is anyone aware of an API that can give me this type of information?

I know I can query various APIs for the coordinates and get the country/state/city location, but what about finding nearby boundaries?

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you're trying to do this in something like real time, so I'm not sure if this will help.

You could use a spatially enabled database like Spatialite or PostGIS and store the country boundary. You could then create a buffer around the boundary of the appropriate distance. This gives you a polygon. You would then take the current position and test if it is inside that polygon.

Since you will be doing this repeatedly there are probably some tricks you could apply to speed up the repeated query. Spatial indices would certainly help.